# How to convert image: cv_32FC1 to cv_16UC1

Tags: c++, opencv

What is the scale factor for this and where is that value coming from?

I have seen 255 floating around for other conversions, but I don't know if that's the case here and I do not just want to blindly follow without a proper explanation.

I am trying `Image.convertTo(Image, CV_16UC1, ???);` but I'm not sure how to calculate the scale factor parameter here.

Can someone assist me in understanding the scale factor parameter for Image.convertTo() ?

Comment: you need to normalize the float image to a known range, then you'll know the scale factor

Comment: what range are your floating points? What range so you want to have in the 16 bit unsigned int?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470255/converting-cv-32fc1-to-cv-16uc1 this question has been answered