# Converting CV_32FC1 to CV_16UC1

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to convert a `float` image that I get from a simulated depth camera to `CV_16UC1`. The camera publishes the depth in `CV_32FC1` format. I tried many ways but the result was not reasonable.

```
cv::Mat depth_cv(512, 512, CV_32FC1, depth);
cv::Mat depth_converted;
depth_cv.convertTo(depth_converted,CV_16UC1);
```

The result is a black image.  If I use a scale factor, the image will be white.

I also tried to do it this way:

```
float depthValueF [512*512];
for (int i=0;i<resolution[1];i++){ // go through the rows (y)
    for (int j=0;j<resolution[0];j++){ // go through the columns (x)
        depthValueOfPixel=depth[i*resolution[0]+j]; // this is location j/i, i.e. x/y
        depthValueF[i*resolution[0]+j] = (depthValueOfPixel) * (65535.0f);
    }
}
```

It was not successful either.

Comment: Please, post the input image you are using.

Comment: WHen u tried to convert ```CV_8UC1``` instead of ```CV_16UC1``` what is the result?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`cv::normalize`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) instead, which will not only convert the image into the proper data type, but it will properly do the scaling for you under the hood.

Therefore:

```
cv::Mat depth_cv(512, 512, CV_32FC1, depth);
cv::Mat depth_converted;
cv::normalize(depth_cv, depth_converted, 0, 65535, NORM_MINMAX, CV_16UC1);
```